# Minimum edit length causes a problem when fixing math typos

Tags: discussion, support

This answer:

[Adding mAh when wiring battery cells in series?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/adding-mah-when-wiring-battery-cells-in-series/20708#20708)

has a typo: "43" instead of "3":

> a 1500 mAh cell will provide 1500 mA for one hour or 500 mA for 43 hours or 850 mA for 2 hours

Trying to correct the typo gives this response while editing:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>       * Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

lol, adding whitespace to the end of the post changes the message to:

> ```
> * Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters; is there something else to improve in this post?
> ```

It seems SO should allow edits shorter than 6 numeric characters if that is indeed the proper change. Conveniently in this case there was a "____" separator so adding 5 more underscores solved everything tidily.

Note also that this is not a trivial edit, but one that changes an incorrect answer into a correct answer.  In other words, math spelling errors are not trivial.

Comment: Note that the six-character limit applies to *suggested* edits only; when you have editing privileges (i.e. 2k rep on a graduated site), you can make as many one-character edits as you want.

Comment: balpha, thanks for the clarification.  I've only edited on *.SO where I have the rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite rare that there's only ever *one* character wrong with a post, so this is to encourage people to make really worthwhile edits.

Yes, in this case that single character is quite important, but  a quick glance at the post shows up the several other issues with the post that needed fixing - minor spelling issues, a broken list, and so on - that made surpassing 6 characters really very easy.

Check the [suggested edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/558) I've made (anonymously as I'm not an EE.SE member) for all those I found on a quick skim read.

It's not a substantial edit, and I'm sure there's probably more in there still to be done, but I got lost in the wall of formulae and didn't want to touch the bits I was unsure of (after all, I'm not an EE expert nor do I know the local expectations on EE.SE).

Comment: DMA, point well made, and thanks for the free editing!

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this I ask the OP to edit the question or answer him/herself. An additional benefit is that people who already responded can see these comments and modify their posts if necessary.